# Arc length of polar function and x interceps

Tags: polar-coordinates, arc-length

> The curve given by $$ r = 4\theta^2, \theta \in [0, \infty) $$ intercepts the x-axis an infinite amount of times. Find the arc length of the curve from the first x-intercept and the third x-intercept. Count $\theta = 0$ as the first x-intercept.

Im not able to find the x-intercepts and therefore not the integration limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x(t)=r\cos (t)=4t^2\cos (t) $$
$$y(t)=4t^2\sin (t) $$

$$x'(t)=t(8\cos (t)-4t\sin (t)) $$
$$y'(t)=t(8\sin (t)+4t\cos (t)) $$

$${x'}^2+{y'}^2=t^2 (64+16t^2) $$

the length is

$$4\int_0^{2\pi}t\sqrt {4+t^2}dt $$
The curve intercepts the x-axis when $t=0 \;,\; t=\pi \;,\; t=2\pi $.

Comment: How did you figure out the x-intercepts?

Comment: @Pame $y=r\sin (\theta)=0$ gives $\theta=0,\pi,2\pi,3\pi.... $

Answer (score 0):

This is a spiral and will intercept the $x$-axis for every $\theta=n\pi$. Therefore, the third intercept will be at $\theta=2\pi$. See the figure below shown for $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$.

The arc length in polar coordinates is given by

$$
\begin{align}
s
&=\int \sqrt{r^2+\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2}~d\theta\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{16\theta^4+64\theta^2}~d\theta\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} 4\theta\sqrt{\theta^2+4}~d\theta\\
&=\frac43(\theta^2+4)^{3/2}\biggr|_0^{2\pi}\\
&=\frac{32}{3}\left[(1+\pi^2)^{3/2}-1 \right]\approx 371.58
\end{align}
$$

I have verified this solution numerically.

[image]